# Ansible conf file changes

Tags: ansible

So, I am a complete noob on Ansible and YAML and I'm trying to learn a bit but this is driving me crazy so far...I am using ansible tower. What I'm trying to do is to replace some text on the ntp.conf file of certain servers and update them with a new server. So my playbook looks like this:

```
---
- hosts: range_1
  tasks:
    - name: ntp change
      become_user: ansible
      blockinfile:
        content: |
          server Server1 iburst
          server Server2 iburst
        dest: /etc/ntp.conf
        insertafter: "Please consider joining the pool"
        marker: "<!-- {mark} ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK -->"
    - name: restart ntp
      service: name=ntpd state=restarted
```

But I am getting the

> PLAY RECAP
>
> ---
>
> Host_1 : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0   failed=0
>   Host_2 : ok=1    changed=0     unreachable=0    failed=0
>   Host_3 : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0

Ansible is running and it does not exit with an error. However, is not making any chnages to the systems. (I assumed because of the changed = 0) I indeed logged on to those systems and no changes have been applied.

I have checked and the syntax is correct but Im not sure what I'm missing. I really need to understand how can I add two servers into the ntp.conf and if a server has some wrong info, to delete it and add just those 2 servers. Any help or guidance will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Please show your `/etc/ntp.conf`. Besides it's a mistake to put an HTML comment `<!-- -->` inside the `ntp.conf` file, the line should start with `#`.

Comment: The /etc/ntp.conf file is different on the systems that's why I'm trying to implement this in. That is why I just want to change this part:
`code`
    # Use public servers from the pool.ntp.org project.
    # Please consider joining the pool (http://www.pool.ntp.org/join.html).
    192.168.0.1
    <whatever irrelevant in here>`code`

also I can felete the comment of <!-- -->, thanks for that :)

Comment: Please show your `/etc/ntp.conf` (edit the question and insert it). It doesn't matter which, do you have a problem to solve, or too much time to argue?

Comment: haha ok, I pasted it in here: http://pastebin.com/ysKgUajA

Comment: Your task works perfectly ok on the file you posted. You can test it locally. The problem is elsewhere - you check wrong servers or whatever; there is no information in the question to give the answer.

Comment: I thought it could be the playbook might have had some syntax errors. So you were actually able tos the changes? will see if I can try some other options

Comment: [playbook](http://pastebin.com/hKtdFPsr) and [file after running](http://pastebin.com/KdCFPdzd) (I just copy-pasted so it even includes your `cat`)

Comment: ok, I see what is happening: I have created a global user called "ansible" that I have been using to set commands or make changes but at this run the message I'm getting is:  FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "The destination directory (/etc) is not writable by the current user."}

so...is not doing the sudo in reality, do I change the ssh config file so it doesnt ask for password on the ansible tower host? or on every machine that I am trying to make the change? or should I just run as a root because is /etc? thanks for illuminating me and for your inputs!

Comment: Found the answer ont he documentation: "become: yes"

Comment: I don't understand why you got `ok` status if you did not have permissions to the file. The status of a task does not change because of verbosity settings. Either you found some bug, or the transcript you included in the question is false.

Answer (score 1):

For anybody that might be reading, when running a playbook from ansible or ansible tower, set the verbose output to 2. When I ran it, it showed me the error:

> AILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "The destination
>   directory (/etc) is not writable by the current user."}

But it was fixed by adding the `become: yes` line on my playbook which it now looks like this:

```
---
- hosts: range_1
  tasks:
    - name: ntp change
      become: yes
      blockinfile:
        content: |
          server Server1 iburst
          server Server2 iburst
        dest: /etc/ntp.conf
        insertafter: "Please consider joining the pool"
        marker: "<!-- {mark} ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK -->"
    - name: restart ntp
      become: yes
      service: name=ntpd state=restarted
```